# How do I send a SMS message

Tags: java, sms

Is there a way to send SMS in java?

Comment: Use Twilio/etc if you need to go across service providers. It also matters what country you're in. Either way, this is off-topic and/or too broad.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: @Dave, I'am in India.@Ben not exactly..I'am new in developing, had done the basic programs and software using awt and swings.My faculty bet me to built and software to send an SMS to a mobile..Need your help :(

Comment: This questions has been asked many times. Simply searching google for "java send sms" produces a wealth of results.

Answer (score -1):

You can just send email to the SMS gate way,

See here: http://newtech.about.com/od/mobile/a/Sms-Gateway-From-Email-To-Sms-Text-Message.htm

Let's say you are using att, the number is 1234567890, so you can send email to 
1234567890@txt.att.net

Sending email is really simple using javamail.

Comment: Not all carriers allow for this method.